Flutter compiling takes all CPU/RAM
I'm trying to compile the default Flutter app in Visual Studio Code (latest version) on a Mac with the M1 chip (version: 14.2.1 (23C71), Sonoma).
When I try to compile my Flutter app (Flutter version: 3.16.5) with just some dependencies in the pubspec.yaml (see below), if I run it on an IOS simulator (iPhone 15 Pro Max - iOS 17.4) it occupies all the CPU of the computer (it does it with even a physical device), while, when I compile it on an Android emulator, it occupies all the RAM.
Here is the pubspec.yaml dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.27.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.8
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.5.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.8
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^25.2.4
  lottie: ^3.1.1

I also noticed that this happened only when I added just a few dependencies.
Once I tried contacting Firebase support, since I thought I was due to the Firebase dependencies. They informed me they didn't notice any issue with the app or the dependencies. Moreover, I face this issue with any other Flutter app, and for this reason, I suppose my machine causes the problem.

Try these:

Hot Reload: See changes instantly without full compiles (great for development).
Profile Builds: Run flutter run --profile to find bottlenecks.
flutter doctor: Check for setup issues.


Hey Syed, I've tried all of these but nothing changes
